# How to insert html tag "id" in an image field in a view

Tags: 7, views, media

I need to add ***id tag*** to an image which is a field of a `view`. Currently it seems only possible to add a class name.

`<img typeof="foaf:Image" ...` must become => `<img id="xxx" typeof="foaf:Image" ...`

Comment: Can't remember off-hand which tpl it is, maybe `views-view-fields.tpl.php`. Edit that (or the correct one) for your field to add the CSS ID to the html and then use the appropriate preprocess to add the `$css_id` var to it.

Comment: In html id's have to be unique. Why not use unique classes? same result...

Comment: @No Sssweat: Class is an option if there is no other solution, but getElementByClassName is less supported by browsers than getElementById.

Comment: @sareed: I checked in views template, but not found.

Comment: @Pierre_C how many rows does your view have? If more than 1, you have to keep in mind that you will need to use some variable in your id, or else all your rows will have the same id, which is a nono.

Answer (score 1):

Searching for typeof="foaf:image" I found that was set by rdf module preprocess_image, not in views. Therefore I added a preprocess function

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_image(&variables){
  // compute first MY_UNIQUE_ID
  $variables['attributes']['id'] = array('MY_UNIQUE_ID');
}
```

now it works.